# Upload the file to a folder and saving the name to the database in yii2

Tags: yii2

Good afternoon!
There is a question about the file upload to yii2. There are two folders in it that will store the original and thumbnail image. At me files are loaded but here the name of a file does not load in a database

Model

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

use yii\imagine\Image;
use Imagine\Image\Box;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "images".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $original_image
 * @property string $prev_image
 */
class Images extends ActiveRecord
{

    public $imageFile;
    public $file_name;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'images';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['prev_image'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['original_image'], 'string'],
            [['imageFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg', 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 * 7],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'original_image' => 'Original Image',
            'prev_image' => 'Prev Image',
        ];
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        $temp=substr(md5(microtime() . rand(0, 9999)), 0, 20);

        if ($this->validate()) {
            $this->imageFile->saveAs('uploads/original/'.$temp.$this->imageFile->baseName . '.' . $this->imageFile->extension);
            $imagine = Image::getImagine();
            $image = $imagine->open('uploads/original/' . $temp.$this->imageFile);
            $image->resize(new Box(250, 150))->save('uploads/prev/' . $temp.$this
                    ->imageFile->baseName . '.' . $this->imageFile->extension, ['quality' => 70]);
            $this->file_name=$temp.$this->imageFile->baseName . '.' . $this->imageFile->extension;

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
namespace app\controllers;


use app\models\Images;
use Yii;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class ImageController extends \yii\web\Controller
{

        public function actionUpload()
    {
        $model = new Images();


        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            $model->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');
            $model->prev_image=$model->file_name;
            $model->original_image=$model->file_name;
            $model->save();

            if ($model->upload()) {
                return;
            }
        }

        return $this->render('upload', ['model' => $model]);
    }

}
```

A question how to save a file name in database? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's because save happens before uplaod action, but you only define file_name in upload function. Save is what saves it in to the database.

Controller should look like this:

```
namespace app\controllers;

use app\models\Images;
use Yii;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class ImageController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionUpload(){

        $model = new Images();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $uploadedFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');
            $model->imageFile = $uploadedFile; 
            $model->prev_image = $uploadedFile->name 
            $model->original_image = $uploadedFile->name 
            $model->save();

            if ($model->upload()) {
                return;
            }
        }

        return $this->render('upload', ['model' => $model]);
    }
}
```